# Add Facebook Application to a fan page through API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

**Is there a way to add a facebook application to a tab in a fan page through API?**
I have developed an app.When a user go to the app I need to display the admin fan pages of the user and ask him to select a page.When a user select a page and click "Add" button, I want to add application into a tab in selected fanpage.
**I know how to get admin fan pages of the user using api.And also I know to detect when my app is running through a fanpage using 'signed request'.**
So can anyone please tell me is there a way to add a facebook application to a fan page through API?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Did you mean you want to running your whole apps in Facebook Page, yes?

Comment: No, Thanks for the reply. I found the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the solution**
It just a straightforward process.I Just had to use this link(**Doesn't need to call api**)
When a user access the app(Not through a fanpage.Can detect when a app is running through a fanpage using ['signed request'](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).) user should derected to this link,

```
<script>
        top.location = 'http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&pages=1';   
</script>
```

It will display the facebook window with all admin pages of the user asking him to add app into a tab in his fan page.

Comment: when you set pages=1, you are do not all the selection of the page. How do I select a page when a user has multiple pages?

Comment: For me, it display all of my fan pages with this code(I have more than 10 fan pages).It display a list of pages and allow me to select one.

Comment: Is there a way to know if the 'this' page has your app added as tab ?

Answer (score 0):

actually, it appears there is a way by using the fb api, which saves the round trip to facebook and back.
the answer is awkwardly situated in the page object page reference (under "tabs"->create)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

you need to make this kind of call to the api:

```
$appId = YOUR_APP_ID;
$pageId = THE_PAGE_TO_ADD_TO;
$apiUrl = "/".$pageId."/tabs";
$addedToPage = $this->facebook->api($apiUrl, "post", array("app_id"=>$appId));
```

good luck!